# Current limitations of a MOSFET

Tags: power-supply, transistors, mosfet, raspberry-pi, led-strip

I am using IRFZ44N for supplying current to the RGB LED strip. The current that is supplied by the three MOSFETs for the three corresponding colors  (R-G-B) is not uniform and much less than required for illuminating efficiently. Is there any other MOSFET that can supply more current? Or should I change the power source?

I am using 12V 1 Amp adapter as a power source.

Here's the schematic of what I am trying to make [image: Schematic in Eagle]

Comment: And how are you controlling them?

Comment: The IRFZ44N is not well suited for direct 3.3V logic level control.

Comment: I am using Raspberry Pi for controlling it. 
So is there any other transistor I could use?  Thank you

Comment: And . . . . . Where is your schematic?

Comment: Voting to close this unless a whole lot more details are provided. There is no way this can be answered as it stands now.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am totally novice to this type of interactions. I'll try my best to be more informative..

Comment: Welcome, Manu. This site has a schematic editor. Show us how you have everything wired.

Comment: That transistor is completely inappropriate for use with a RPi.

Comment: Please suggest a better transistor if you know Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  thank you..

Answer (score 4):

You may see that the mosfet won't turn on all the way. The datasheet shows that it's Voltage Gate - Source Threshold (V<sub>GS(TH)</sub>) is 3V typical, 4V max. Meaning that it may barely work at the RPI'S 3.3V level. That Mosfet is not well suited for 3.3V logic level applications. At 3.3V, the FET won't even pass fractions of an Amp.

#### The RPI's 3.3V logic isn't turning the Mosfet on all the way.

If you want to stick to that mosfet, you could use a simple NPN transistor as a driver. A 2n3904 or 2n2222 or any similar. It's not critical, it's just a switch. **Logic will be reversed, so on the RPi, A logic High/3.3V will turn the leds OFF.**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBH7il.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

***The RPI's ground and the 12V supply's ground need to be tied together as well.*** If anything, make sure you have that happening right now as that's a common mistake. It could be as simple as not having connected it right.

Otherwise, you want a **"Logic Level Mosfet"**, one that has a V<sub>GS</sub> voltage of 3.3V.

That said, depending on how long your led strips are, an 1 Amp supply may not be enough. Make sure the fully on White (All 3 channels) current is under that amount.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. 
Yes, the R-Pi and power supply grounds are connected.
And I am actually controlling the intensity of the lights by controlling the GATE terminal values from R-Pi. Will this switch help in that case?

Comment: @ManuJr it shouldn't affect it noticeably if at all. Just like I said though, the logic is inverted, so RPI output High is LED OFF, and Output Low is LED On. So invert your numbers.